# WPF- Bind object property to control in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml-binding

I have clearly stated my issue below.

Thank you in advance
-->

I have a public class:

```
public class class1
{
 int iVal;
 public int IVal
 {
  get { return iVal; }
  set { iVal=value;  }
 }
}
```

I am going to create an object of  type `class1` inside my mainWindow.cs.

```
class1 ob = new class1();
```

In the mainWindow.xaml file I have a `TextBlock`.

My question is how to bind the `ob.IVal` value to the `TextBlock` using XAML binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IVal, Mode=OneWay}"/>   
// this binding is not working for me.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to set the `DataContext` for the XAML tree.  In mainWindow.cs, write it like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class1 ob { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ob = new class1();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ob;
    }
}
```

Then the binding to `IVal` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response it was really help for me. I have one more question. If I have the testblock inside a grid. Can I set the data context to grid (grid.DataContext=ob;) to solve my issue rather than setting it to window or the textblock?

Comment: @dash yes, that's correct, you can set the data context to the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you missed to set the `DataContext` property - as dbasemen suggested - but it's still not enough.

You set the binding mode to `OneWay` which means that the communication goes from the source to the target: `Class1.IVal -> TextBlock.Text` in this case.

But you have to send notification about the changes of the IVal property, which means you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event handler and raise the `Propertychanged` event when the IVal prop is set.

You find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) how to do it .